# Why this program is giving wrong output for palindrome?

Tags: java

I am making the program forthe largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
But program is giving product of 999*999=998001
Can anyone tell what's wrong in this code?

Program-

```
public class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int p=0,temp=0;

        for(int i=100;i<=999;i++)
        {
            for(int j=100;j<=999;j++)
            {
                p=i*j;
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(p));

                sb.reverse();
                if((sb.toString()).equals(Integer.toString(p))  && p>temp)
                {
                    temp=p;
                }
            }
        }       
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: because `999*999=998001`?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `;` :

```
if((sb.toString()).equals(Integer.toString(p))  && p>temp);
                                                          ^
```

It ends the if statement, so the following block, with `temp=p;` is always executed.

Remove it and you'll get

```
906609
```

Comment: oh sorry,but after removing semi-colon again i am getting same o/p

Comment: @Stone I actually tried your code after removing the `;` and got `906609`.

Comment: @ Eran, k ,thanks i got it